# Samsung Galaxy S10e restarts when turning on hotspot

Tags: samsung, wifi-hotspot, reboot

My Samsung Galaxy S10e restarts when I turn on the hotspot.

I have checked for updates but they are not available.

How can I fix it?

Comment: If your S10e has internet access why do you start Hotspot to check for updates?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue to me. I have the same phone, but I've never experienced that, neither on stock or modified roms. Try factory resetting the phone and let it update to the latest available version. If it still happens, bad news.